# Is vala a cross platform language?

Tags: linux, windows, cross-platform, vala

Vala is a programming language with C# same syntactic, valac compiles vala program to C source code, is it possible to run my vala program on windows os?

Comment: You might end up disappointed if you expect Vala to have the exact same syntax as C#. It's similar, but not identical.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can easily port your Vala applications on Windows by two means:

1. Run valac on Windows by using the mingw compiler on Windows
2. Use mingw on Linux to cross-compile the generated C source for Windows

Both work very well, but I suggest to do the second because Vala on Linux is more up-to-date than on Windows.

Comment: tnx,can you help me to compile a vala file to win exe file using mingw?

Comment: First generate the C files with valac -C, after that it's all about cross-compiling a C file, it's not a matter of Vala anymore. Fetch the necessary DLLs and compile the C files with gcc-mingw.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "does it compile on Windows?", then see the "OS" section in the infobox on the right here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(programming_language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_%28programming_language%29) and here are the instructions: http://live.gnome.org/Vala/ValaOnWindows

Comment: The link appears to be dead. Probably gnome.org has been reorganized.

Comment: @XTL yep, looks like that. However, this one is still alive: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Documentation, the link is available from there, but it says the page is not yet created...